# Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-filetransferutil". Please try adding it again

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have created a new Cordova plugin and deployed it on npm but when I am trying to install in the Cordova project I am getting an error 'Cannot find plugin.xml for plugin "cordova-plugin-filetransferutil". Please try adding it again.'

package.json

```
{
  "_from": "cordova-plugin-filetransferutil",
  "_id": "cordova-plugin-filetransferutil@0.0.5",
  "_location": "/cordova-plugin-filetransferutil",
  "_phantomChildren": {},
  "_requested": {
  "type": "tag",
  "registry": true,
  "raw": "cordova-plugin-filetransferutil",
  "name": "cordova-plugin-filetransferutil",
  "escapedName": "cordova-plugin-filetransferutil",
  "rawSpec": "",
  "saveSpec": null,
  "fetchSpec": "latest"
   },
  "name": "cordova-plugin-filetransferutil",
  "version": "0.0.5",
  "cordova": {
  "id": "cordova-plugin-filetransferutil",
  "platforms": ["android"]
  },
  "keywords": ["ecosystem:cordova"],  
  "author": {
             "name": "Hitesh Thakor"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": ""
}
```

plugin.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<plugin id="cordova-plugin-filetransferutil" version="0.0.5"
    xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <name>FileTransferUtilPlugin</name>
    <js-module name="FileTransferUtilPlugin" src="www/FileTransferUtilPlugin.js">
        <clobbers target="cordova.plugins" />
    </js-module>
    <platform name="android">
        <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
            <feature name="FileTransferUtilPlugin">
                <param name="android-package" value="cordova.plugin.filetransferutil.FileTransferUtilPlugin" />
            </feature>
        </config-file>
        <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml"></config-file>
        <source-file src="src/android/FileTransferUtilPlugin.java" target-dir="src/cordova/plugin/filetransferutil/FileTransferUtilPlugin" />
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

I am not getting where I am making mistake. Please advise if I am missing anything.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing your own plugin using

```
 cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-filetransferutil
```

know that it takes at least 1 day for the cordova ecosystem to register this plugin via npm.